# Implementing unique_copy with templated comp function - type inference

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, type-inference

I have implemented my version of `unique_copy` and it works. The problem is that I have to call it this way:

```
my_unique_copy(
    in.begin(),                 // ok
    in.end(),                   // ok
    out.begin(),                // ok
    equals<Container::iterator> // <--sucks
);
```

What I don't like is the equals function `equals<Container::iterator>` has to be explicitly instantiated with `Container::iterator`. I think the type might be inferred from `in.begin()`, which is of type `Container::iterator`. I tried to declare `equals` as `bool()(Iterator,Iterator)` in the function prototype, but it failed 'orribly.

```
../untitled2/main.cpp:20:32: error: 'parameter' declared as function returning a function
        bool()(Iterator,Iterator) equals){
                                ^
../untitled2/main.cpp:20:34: error: expected ')' before 'equals'
        bool()(Iterator,Iterator) equals){
                                  ^
../untitled2/main.cpp:20:34: error: expected initializer before 'equals'
../untitled2/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../untitled2/main.cpp:41:79: error: 'my_unique_copy' was not declared in this scope
     my_unique_copy(in.begin(),in.end(),out.begin(),equals<Container::iterator>);
                                                                               ^
```

This is the code:

```
template <typename Iterator>
bool equals(Iterator fst, Iterator snd){
    return *fst==*snd;
}

bool myfunction (int i, int j) {
  return (i==j);
}

template <typename Iterator, typename Comparator>
void my_unique_copy(Iterator begin,
       Iterator end,
       Iterator out_begin,
       Comparator equals){
    if (begin==end){
        return;
    }

    *out_begin=*begin;
    ++begin;

    while (begin!=end){
        if (!equals(out_begin, begin)){
            *(++out_begin)=*begin;
        }
        ++begin;
    }
}

int main(){
    using Container = vector<int>;
    Container in{1,2,2,3};
    Container out(4);

    my_unique_copy(in.begin(),in.end(),out.begin(),equals<Container::iterator>);
    for_each(out.begin(), out.end(), [](int v){cout<<v<<" ";});

    cout<<endl;

    unique_copy(in.begin(),in.end(),out.begin(),myfunction);
    for_each(out.begin(), out.end(), [](int v){cout<<v<<" ";});
}
```

This is what I want:

```
my_unique_copy(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), equals);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement `equals` as a functor rather than as a function template, you can basically get what you want:

```
struct equals {
    template<typename Iterator>
    bool operator ()(Iterator fst, Iterator snd) const {
        return *fst == *snd;
    }
};

// ...

my_unique_copy(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), equals{});
```

Note that because the standard library [already has an `equal_to` functor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to), you should probably choose a different name that better connotes the difference between your functor and `std::equal_to`, e.g. `iter_equals`. Or, better yet, you should just *use* `std::equal_to` instead of reinventing the wheel by dereferencing the iterators as you call `equals` instead of passing in the iterators themselves (this is what the standard library algorithms do).

Comment: Okay, I changed the code to compare values (const ref) instead of the iterators. Interestingly `equal_to<int>{}` , `str_equals{}` and `fun_equals<int>` work, while `fun_equals` and `equal_to{}` do not. What exactly does `{}` mean with structs? Would it be possible to make the latter two work without explicit template instantiation?

Comment: @Slazer : In this context, `{}` [value-initializes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) the structs (effectively default-constructing them). With C++14, `equal_to<>{}` will behave the way you want, but with C++11 you do need to specify the type explicitly (easily obtained via `decltype` or [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) for generic code).